# Unexpected Token Error in React When Hosting on a Subpath Using Nginx + Traefik

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I have a Docker container running a production React app alongside Nginx for hosting its static files.

**Dockerfile**

```dockerfile
FROM node:16.5.0-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV PUBLIC_URL /trade-journal
RUN npm ci --production
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```conf
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        # static file hosting location
        root                /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files           $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Above, you can see that I'm setting a `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable. This is because I'd like the app to be hosted on a subpath, like this: `domain.com/trade-journal`. I'm using Traefik to route to this subpath because in the future, I'd like to add more subpaths for other apps.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yml
reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.8
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
frontend:
    build:
      context: ./trade-journal/client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "trade-journal-client"
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`[MY-PUBLIC-IP-HERE]`) && PathPrefix(`/trade-journal`)
      - traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    links:
      - "backend:be"
```

I understand that React is designed to run on root by default, so I added:

1. `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">` in `public/index.html`, and
2. `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to `BrowserRouter`

I've also alternatively tried setting the subpath with `homepage` in `package.json`, and writing the `basename` as just `/trade-journal`.

Either way, I get the same error in my browser on a blank page:

[image]

For whatever reason, it can't load `http://domain/trade-journal/static/js/main.93967f03.js`. Actually, I can't even view the code in that file, or any other JS or CSS files in that directory through the browser (even though I can when I `bin/sh` into the running container); I only ever get a blank index file.

I assume that the problem has to do with routing because when I remove any having to do with the subpath and host on `/`, the React app loads correctly.

I'm very new to hosting and deploying. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I fixed it. I needed to use alias, and include the subpath in nginx as well. Now, I'm going to see if I can make this solution any more DRY (so I don't have to repeat the subpath so many times). If anyone has any suggestions, let me know.

```
location /trade-journal {
    # static file hosting location
    alias               /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files           $uri $uri/ /trade-journal/index.html;
}
```